# Dividir una columna de texto y numeros en dos columas con polars

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con la libreria polars de Python, estoy explorando un poco con ella y poniendola a prueba en diferentes situaciones que manejo a diario con pandas, me encontre con una situacion en donde tengo una columna con numeros y texto que tiene la siguiente estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un csv separado por ; pero la penultima columna tiene algunos registros en la cadena que contienen la palabra extra, esto me impide castear la columna a tipo numerico, mi objetivo para no perder informacion es crear dos columnas derivadas de la columna que causa el inconveniente,en una tener la palabra extra si existe y en otra unicamente el numero, he intentado con el siguiete codigo :

```
import polars as pl 

loteria = loteria = pl.read_csv('ventas-por-loteria.csv',infer_schema_length=100000,try_parse_dates=True,separator=";")

loteria = loteria.with_columns(
    pl.col("SORTEO").apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[0]).alias('EXTRA'), 
    pl.col("SORTEO").apply(lambda x: x.split(" ")[1]).alias('NUMERO') 
    )
```

el metodo `split` devuelve una lista pero esperaba que en caso de que no tuviera la palabra extra, me devolviera un None como lo hace pandas pero el solo crea una lista con un unico elemento y al acceder a `[1]` ese indice no existe. Me podrian ayudar a manejar esta excepcion porfavor, gracias por su ayuda

edit:
el csv esta disponible en datos abiertos de bogota https://datosabiertos.bogota.gov.co/dataset/5de8c1ef-e8af-469e-bfc1-1f3097b32155?_external=True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento de `split` no es extraño, de hecho concuerda con como actúa `str.split` y `pandas.Series.str.split`:

```
>>> datos = ["2702", "Extra 003"]

>>> [dato.split(" ") for dato in datos]
[['2702'], ['Extra', '003']]

>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series(datos)
>>> s.str.split(" ")
0          [2702]
1    [Extra, 003]
dtype: object

>>> import polars as pl
>>> s = pl.Series(datos)
>>> s.str.split(" ") 
shape: (2,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["2702"]
    ["Extra", "003"]
]
```

Tal como quieres separar la columna, en vez de usar `split` creo que una expresión regular y [`polars.Expr.str.extract_groups`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.extract_groups.html) es mejor en este caso:

```
import polars as pl


loteria = pl.read_csv(
    "https://datosabiertos.bogota.gov.co/dataset/5de8c1ef-e8af-469e-bfc1-1f3097b32155/resource/31558919-938c-4160-afcc-7d2fc8bf95c9/download/ventas-por-loteria.csv",
    infer_schema_length=100000,
    try_parse_dates=True,
    separator=";"
    )


REGEX = r'(?<EXTRA>Extra)?\s?(?<NUMERO>\d+)'

loteria = loteria.with_columns(
    loteria.select(pl.col('SORTEO').str.extract_groups(REGEX))
    .select(
        pl.col('SORTEO').struct["EXTRA"],
        pl.col('SORTEO').struct["NUMERO"]
        ))

print(loteria.head(20))
```

> ```
> ┌──────┬───────┬────────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┬───────┬────────┐
> │ AÑO  ┆ MES   ┆ FECHA      ┆ SORTEO    ┆ VENTA BRUTA     ┆ EXTRA ┆ NUMERO │
> │ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---       ┆ ---             ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
> │ i64  ┆ str   ┆ date       ┆ str       ┆ str             ┆ str   ┆ str    │
> ╞══════╪═══════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╪═══════╪════════╡
> │ 2021 ┆ enero ┆ 2021-01-07 ┆ 2570      ┆ $ 946.135.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2570   │
> │ 2021 ┆ enero ┆ 2021-01-14 ┆ 2571      ┆ $ 934.545.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2571   │
> │ 2021 ┆ enero ┆ 2021-01-21 ┆ 2572      ┆ $ 987.100.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2572   │
> │ 2021 ┆ enero ┆ 2021-01-28 ┆ 2573      ┆ $ 1.079.700.000 ┆ null  ┆ 2573   │
> │ …    ┆ …     ┆ …          ┆ …         ┆ …               ┆ …     ┆ …      │
> │ 2021 ┆ mayo  ┆ 2021-05-06 ┆ 2586      ┆ $ 873.130.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2586   │
> │ 2021 ┆ mayo  ┆ 2021-05-13 ┆ 2587      ┆ $ 920.105.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2587   │
> │ 2021 ┆ mayo  ┆ 2021-05-15 ┆ Extra 003 ┆ $ 4.106.520.000 ┆ Extra ┆ 003    │
> │ 2021 ┆ mayo  ┆ 2021-05-20 ┆ 2588      ┆ $ 971.190.000   ┆ null  ┆ 2588   │
> └──────┴───────┴────────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┴───────┴────────┘
> ```

La expresión regular no tiene mucha complicación:

```
(?<EXTRA>Extra)?\s?(?<NUMERO>\d+)
|______________||_||____________|
        |        |        |
        |        |        2º grupo de captura con nombre NUMERO (Un dígito o mas)
        |        Cualquier espacio en blanco
        1º grupo de captura opcional (?) con nombre EXTRA (literal "Extra")
```